# Appending results of two LAMBDA functions

Tags: google-sheets

I have the two below LAMBDA functions

```
=LAMBDA(z,filter(z,index(z,,17)=max(index(z,,17))))(IMPORTRANGE("1l_xGjh4YNCANLg-npQWzlXXpQJ3nidC4RzBvR62efuE", "Overview!A2:Z"))

=LAMBDA(z,filter(z,index(z,,12)=max(index(z,,12))))(IMPORTRANGE("1madkVso_zaoU9MH2gvtVlTaT2iJ9nMcCxS8ux0Vpz14", "Overview!A2:Z"))
```

How can I combine them to ensure the data is stacked on top of each other/appended? I know you can use QUERY but I am reluctant to use this because one column in my dataset is of hyperlink format and QUERY would just import it as a string (and hence wouldn't be clickable).

I tried the below curly brackets format but it doesn't work (error message is "an Array Literal is missing values"):

```
={(LAMBDA(z,filter(z,index(z,,17)=max(index(z,,17))))(IMPORTRANGE("1l_xGjh4YNCANLg-npQWzlXXpQJ3nidC4RzBvR62efuE", "Overview!A2:Z")));(LAMBDA(z,filter(z,index(z,,12)=max(index(z,,12))))(IMPORTRANGE("1madkVso_zaoU9MH2gvtVlTaT2iJ9nMcCxS8ux0Vpz14", "Overview!A2:Z")))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
    =lambda(z,filter(z,index(z,,1)<>""))({IFERROR(LAMBDA(z,filter(z,index(z,,17)=max(index(z,,17))))(IMPORTRANGE("1l_xGjh4YNCANLg-npQWzlXXpQJ3nidC4RzBvR62efuE", "Overview!A2:R")),MAKEARRAY(1,18,LAMBDA(r,c,IFERROR(1/0))));
IFERROR(LAMBDA(z,filter(z,index(z,,12)=max(index(z,,12))))(IMPORTRANGE("1madkVso_zaoU9MH2gvtVlTaT2iJ9nMcCxS8ux0Vpz14", "Overview!A2:R")),MAKEARRAY(1,18,LAMBDA(r,c,IFERROR(1/0))))})
```

Comment: This generates a result but the hyperlink column I mentioned above is returned as a string.

Comment: try the updated formula